# IPv6 support for Azure other than the load balancer thing

Tags: azure, cloud, ipv6, paas, azure-virtual-network

I have two questions regarding azure and IPv6. I understand that you can assign private IPv6s to VMs and then connect them to a load balance with a public IPv6, but is there anyway to use IPv6 with other resources in Azure, such as, cloud services, virtual networks, Application gateway, NSG, VPN Gateway, App Services, SQL databases, and SQL DWH?

Also,
I see that it says you cannot upgrade VMs to IPv6 and you need to make new ones. Does that mean that you would only have to remake VMs that were created before the time in which IPv6 support was released? Or does it mean you have to remake every VM that wasnt created specifically with the feature of IPv6?

Comment: I'm sorry, this question is off-topic here. Please ask it on server fault.

Answer (score 3):

> is there anyway to use IPv6 with other resources in Azure, such as,
>   cloud services, virtual networks, Application gateway, NSG, VPN
>   Gateway, App Services, SQL databases, and SQL DWH?

Unfortunately, we **can't** use IPv6 without LB right now, because the public IPv6 addresses cannot be assigned to a VM, they **only** can be assigned to a load balancer.
The IPv6 address of the VMs are private, the IPv6 Internet client **cannot** communicate directly with the IPv6 address of the VMs, the internet-facing load balancer routes the IPv6 packages to the private IPv6 addresses of the VMs using network address translation (NAT).

> Does that mean that you would only have to remake VMs that were
>   created before the time in which IPv6 support was released? Or does it
>   mean you have to remake every VM that wasnt created specifically with
>   the feature of IPv6?

No, if we want to use IPv6, we should deploy LB and new vms, because we can't add other VMs to the **Availability set** which used for the LB.  so
**you may not upgrade existing VMs to use IPv6 addresses. You must deploy new VMs.**

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: If it helps, please mark is as an answer, it will help others.

Comment: It is application gateway still not supporting IPv6 ?